# Python: Recursive Structs

Tags: python, recursion, structure, thrift

I have problem with [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) code generator or python.

Code sample (generated by thrift):

```
class SomeClass:
    spec = (
            (1, (SomeClass, SomeClass.spec)),
    )
```

Error message:

```
NameError: name 'SomeClass' is not defined
```

So I found [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2642) in thrift jira (still opened since 2014). Suggested solution pretty bad.

Can I avoid this problem somehow?

In best case solution in *.thrift or *.py files, that can be changed before or after generation manually.

Comment: You need to include desired behavior in your question.

Comment: expected behavior - no errors in spec tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, thats python's genered code contains useless field

```
SomeClass.spec
```

So i just delete it.

I compared this with java generated code.

**If someone will use my solution dont forget to change generated methods, thats check, when your spec!=None**

Comment: Could you please bring the last sentence (the bold one) in a fom anyone can understand? There are so many errors, it's hard to guess what you are trying to say.

Comment: i mean if we delete "SomeClass.spec" we must remove all following mentions

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the code with the following code snippet, Note: it is using lists instead of tuples since tuples are immutable.

```
class SomeClass:
    spec = None
    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.spec = []
        cls.spec.append( [ 1 , (cls, cls.spec) ] )

SomeClass.init()

print( SomeClass.spec )       # [[1, (<class SomeClass>, [...])]]
```

Another solution without class methods

```
class SomeClass:
    spec = None

SomeClass.spec = []
SomeClass.spec.append( [ 1 , (SomeClass, SomeClass.spec) ] )

print( SomeClass.spec )       # [[1, (<class SomeClass>, [...])]]
```

Comment: yes, it works, but i cant use @classmethod outside of method.

Comment: I have added a solution without class method

Comment: i guess works only outside of class :)
first solution was pretty close, but at __init__ stage ima already want have access to spec tuple

Comment: also, how about [...]? this is infinite list.
thats not exacly, what i want
i want, thats list can handle SomeClass, but usage in other methods

Comment: This is meaning of the code - It defines a infinite list.

Comment: yes
and thats why this was wrong.
however i user your second solution, but with removed SomeClass.spec.
and that, what i need.
thanks.